# What is the Default Browser of Client's computer in windows?

Tags: windows, networking, browser, windows-registry

Is there a way to find what is the default browser on a client's windows machine?

Is there a registry key or some other property that can help to find what is their default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\<protocol>\UserChoice\Progid
```

where  is http, https, mapi, ftp etc)
[image]

You will see that in my case FirefoxURL is my default for HTTP making Firefox my default browser for HTTP.

Other browser records include:

- FirefoxURL (Firefox)
- ChromeHTML (Chrome)
- IE.HTTP (Internet Explorer)

Hope this helps.

Bonus points:

```
    $computerList = @("Server1", "server2")
$cred = Get-Credential

ForEach ($Computer in $computerList) {

    New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $cred | Out-Null
    Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ScriptBlock {
        Write-Host $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Write-Host (Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice).Progid
        Write-Host "`n"
    }
    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

}
```

Something like this should help.. although it relies ona user being logged on and you having powershell remoting enabled (to enable powershell remoting, run Enable-PSRemoting -Force as a startup computer script via group policy)

Also, you can install PowerShell 4 on your windows 7 machines to allow this functionality - see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx for more

Comment: Thank you! Now I just need to retrieve this piece of information using PowerShell.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer :)

Comment: Great! :) 'Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice\" |% {$_.ProgId} 
' this works too. So what's the difference?

Comment: Mine grabs the one property from the registry key "Object" and displays it.  Yours grabs the whole key and then does a "where" comparison to find only the property you want.. 2 different methods that do pretty much exactly the same thing in 2 different ways to get the samw end result... I love PowerShell

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to edit the registry. Go to `Control Panel` -> `All Control Panel Items` -> `Default Programs` -> `Associate a file type or protocol with a program`.

Below the list of extensions (including `.htm` and `.html`) you will see the protocols, and you can view or change the associated program. The protocol list includes `HTTP`, `HTTPS` and `FTP`.

This applies to Win8.1. WinXP uses `Explorer` -> `Tools` -> `Folder Options...` -> `File Types`, and the protocols precede the extensions. I'm not sure about every intermediate version.